# Make subsection look like paragraph in appendix

Tags: numbering, paragraphs, sections-paragraphs

I want to make a subsection look like a paragraph, while the numbering should stay like that of a subsection. Here is an image for clarification.

[image]

So there should be normal text besides the numbering and also it should support referencing. The paragraph command doesn't work for that since the numbering level is deeper than just B.1, B.2 and it doesn't support referencing.
(I made the "like that" image by using `\paragraph{B.1}` instead of the section command).

Here is my current code.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[page]{appendix}

\begin{document}

\section{First chapter}

\begin{appendices}
\section{Some Section}

\section{Exercises}
\section{} Describe what an elephant looks like.
\label{ex1}

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  `\titleformat` from `titlesec` on entering the `appendices` environment:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, english]{article}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[page]{appendix}

\begin{document}

\section{First chapter}
\subsection{A subsection}
Some text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text

\begin{appendices}
\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]{\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}

\section{Some Section}
\section{Exercises}
\subsection{}Describe what an elephant looks like.
\label{ex1}

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

[image]